# Memory leak while handling exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks

I just move to C++ from C, and currently slicing my path through exceptions.

I'm having a hard time figuring out why am I getting a memory leak in this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>  /* I/O */
#include <exception> /* exception */
#include <cstdlib>   /* stdlib */

using namespace std;

void Bar()
{
    throw exception();
}

void Foo()
{
    int *ip = new int;

    try
    {
        Bar();    
    }
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        cerr << "Foo: Exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
        delete ip;
        exit(1);
    }

    delete ip;
}

int main()
{
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something crucial here, but can't point at it. Any idea?

Valgrind's output:

```
==21857== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21857== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21857== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21857== Command: ./a.out
==21857== 
Foo: Exception caught: std::exception
==21857== 
==21857== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21857==     in use at exit: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==21857==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 72,844 bytes allocated
==21857== 
==21857== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==21857==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21857==    by 0x4ECD8FF: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==21857==    by 0x108CCC: Bar() (ex33.cpp:9)
==21857==    by 0x108D0C: Foo() (ex33.cpp:18)
==21857==    by 0x108DBD: main (ex33.cpp:31)
==21857== 
==21857== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21857==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21857==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21857==      possibly lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==21857==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21857==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21857== 
==21857== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21857== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: This is what `std::unique_ptr` is for. You should never assign the result of `new` to a `T*` raw pointer. Further more, you should almost never use `new` to dynamically create objects anymore. Prefer using containers to store objects or use `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` to avoid resource leaks. Here, you would use `auto ip = std::make_unique<int>();`.

Comment: [Read this about exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084861/is-it-good-practice-to-use-exit-in-void-function-for-error).  You shouldn't be calling it like that, unless you want your customers / users to be angry.

Comment: "Other than by throwing or rethrowing the exception, the catch-clause after a regular try block (not function-try-block) may be exited with a return, continue, break, goto, or by reaching the end of its compound-statement. In any case, this destroys the exception object (unless an instance of std::exception_ptr exists that refers to it). " from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch The leaked memory is the exception objection. It's properly destroyed by the `catch` block that catches it. If you `exit` from the `catch` block then the exception is not destroyed and leaks.

Comment: Remove `ip` and its associated code; you'll still have the same issue. The memory allocated to `ip` is properly released in both branches of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should't call exit in C++ really. Local objects destructors will not be called. And cause stack will not be unwounded, looks like destructor of exception also will not be called.

From standard:

> 18.1.2 When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (18.3); “nearest” means the
>   handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following
>   the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control and
>   not yet exited
>
> 18.1.3 Throwing an exception copy-initializes (11.6, 15.8) a temporary object, called the exception object. An lvalue denoting the temporary
>   is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler
>   (18.3). If the type of the exception object would be an incomplete
>   type or a pointer to an incomplete type other than cv void the program
>   is ill-formed.

Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called. Quote from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)

Comment: Thanks! Especially for this: "looks like destructor of exception also will not be called." It's not an easy path towards OOP :(

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, replacing `exit(1)` from within `Foo()` to `return;` fixed the memory leak.

So, my follow-up question, why can't I call `exit()` from `Foo()`?

Comment: Remove `ip` entirely and see if there is still a memory leak. It maybe a false positive from existing abruptly with `exit`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There still is!

Comment: @MrBens Then you don't actually have a memory leak. It's probably a standard library resource not being freed cleanly on `exit`. It probably doesn't matter because it only happens when the process ends, except that it produces this false positive result.